# does buoyancy depend on shape and volume?

Tags: buoyancy

IF buoyancy is due to the pressure differential as we go deeper in a liquid, then that pressure differential should depend on the vertical dimension of the immersed object. Eg. if we have a long cylinder vertically placed, the pressure differential between its top surface and its bottom surface will be bigger than the differential of a shorter cylinder. Is this true?

Comment: Buoyancy depends only on the weight of the fluid that a given object displaces.

Comment: It does not depend on the shape in incompressible liquids. In practice the compressibility of the object is usually the bigger issue, e.g. for balloons, blimps and submarines.

Comment: Isn't my logic sensible? Why it is not correct?

Comment: @ergon: Pressure is not a direct factor in buoyancy; see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59962/how-dense-fluid-affect-the-buoyancy-force

Comment: It depends but effect is very negligible unless you have a very much vertically extended object.